How to properly expand multiple variables in ansible when: statement?
I have the following play working correctly as expected:
- name: Identify next available hostname    
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:      
    NEXT_HOSTNAME: "{{ HOSTNAME_CONVENTION }}{{ '{:02d}'.format(item) }}"    
  loop: "{{ range(1, 99) | reverse | list }}"
  when: "'host-name{:02d}'.format(item) not in EXISTING_HOSTNAMES

Where EXISTING_HOSTNAMES is a list of non-sequential hostnames already assigned and HOSTNAME_CONVENTION is set to 'host-name'.
My goal is to substitute out the "host-name" text in the when statement with the HOSTNAME_CONVENTION variable similar in manner to how the "NEXT_HOSTNAME" variable value is being built.
Substituting out the "when" line to
when: "'HOSTNAME_CONVENTION{:02d}'.format(item) not in EXISTING_HOSTNAMES

allows the play to run, but it does not correctly evaluate, as I expect it to skip host-name01, host-name02, and host-name04 since they are already assigned, whereas with the static "host-name" text on the when line, it does correctly skip host-name01, host-name02, and host-name04.
Substituting out the "when" line to
when: "HOSTNAME_CONVENTION'{:02d}'.format(item) not in EXISTING_HOSTNAMES

fails completely with "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'string'"

You're probably better off writing a custom module via Python. They are pretty simple to unit test with Python's unittest module. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html

Declare the host convention, start, stop, format, and index
  hc: host-name
  start: 1
  stop: '20'
  frmt: "%0{{ stop|length }}d"
  index: |
    {% for i in range(start, stop|int) %}
    {{ frmt|format(i) }} {% endfor %}

give
  frmt: '%02d'
  index: |-
    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Create all hostnames
  hn: "{{ [hc] | product(index|split) | map('join') }}"

gives
  hn:
  - host-name01
  - host-name02
  - host-name03
  - host-name04
  - host-name05
  - host-name06
  - host-name07
  - host-name08
  - host-name09
  - host-name10
  - host-name11
  - host-name12
  - host-name13
  - host-name14
  - host-name15
  - host-name16
  - host-name17
  - host-name18
  - host-name19

Given the list of existing hostnames. For example,
  existing_hostnames: [host-name01, host-name02, host-name04]

remove them from the list of all hostnames
  result: "{{ hn | difference(existing_hostnames) | sort }}"

gives what you probably want
  result:
  - host-name03
  - host-name05
  - host-name06
  - host-name07
  - host-name08
  - host-name09
  - host-name10
  - host-name11
  - host-name12
  - host-name13
  - host-name14
  - host-name15
  - host-name16
  - host-name17
  - host-name18
  - host-name19



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hc: host-name
    start: 1
    stop: '20'
    frmt: "%0{{ stop|length }}d"
    index: |
      {% for i in range(start, stop|int) %}
      {{ frmt|format(i) }} {% endfor %}
    hn: "{{ [hc] | product(index|split) | map('join') }}"
    existing_hostnames: [host-name01, host-name02, host-name04]
    result: "{{ hn | difference(existing_hostnames) | sort }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hc
    - debug:
        var: frmt
    - debug:
        var: index
    - debug:
        var: hn
    - debug:
        var: result


Q: Addition of the first filter in the result variable.
A: It's simpler to concatenate the result if you want the first item only
  existing_indexes: "{{ existing_hostnames | map('replace', hc, '') }}"
  result: "{{ hc }}{{ index|split|difference(existing_indexes)|first }}"

give
  existing_indexes:
  - '01'
  - '02'
  - '04'

  result: host-name03

Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hc: host-name
    start: 1
    stop: '20'
    frmt: "%0{{ stop|length }}d"
    index: |
      {% for i in range(start, stop|int) %}
      {{ frmt|format(i) }} {% endfor %}

    existing_hostnames: [host-name01, host-name02, host-name04]
    existing_indexes: "{{ existing_hostnames | map('replace', hc, '') }}"
    result: "{{ hc }}{{ index|split|difference(existing_indexes)|first }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: existing_indexes
    - debug:
        var: result



Thank you! This achieved what I was looking for with the addition of the "first" filter in the result variable, and appears to be cleaner than the way I was trying to perform it!

The code can simplified if you need the first item only. I added an example. You're welcome!
